# Lua scripts for RateLimiter in redisson

Tags: redis, redisson

I am using redisson client for redis and was looking to implement RateLimiter for the gateway we are building. It seems like the client is using lua scripts for implementation which unfortunately is not allowed in our company(by default). Any specific reason why lua script was preferred over transactions.

Answer (score 0):

Lua scripts executed in one call instead of transactions and can modify data right in the script. As for transactions they needs to be executed in multiple requests if you modify data with result of command executed in transaction.